# Formula Fields Error: Incorrect parameter type for function 'ISPICKVAL()'. Expected Text Literal, received Text

Tags: formula

I'm trying to compare if the picklist's value is equal to current year.

I tried several approaches but no success.

```
ISPICKVAL(Last_Filing_Year__c,""&TEXT(YEAR(TODAY())))
```

---

```
ISPICKVAL(Last_Filing_Year__c,TEXT(YEAR(TODAY())))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try

```
VALUE(TEXT(Last_Filing_Year__c)) = YEAR(TODAY())
```

Answer (score 1):

@Vamsi has a working one, another alternative is

```
TEXT(Last_Filing_Year__c) = TEXT(YEAR(TODAY()))
```